# Static ComboBox in VS LightSwitch

Tags: c#, combobox, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a screen in LightSwitch, which shows some data items. The User has the ability to Click on a button in Command Bar to start custom routines to print labels, do mail merge,...

now what i want to achieve is:
instead of directly running the routines for mail merge and labels i want to ask the user about the paper format.

My approach is: Show a modal window which contains just a combobox with the options (e.g. C4, letter, A4, A5,...) and a button to continue.

So far so good, i added a modal window and everything seems to work perfect BUT: how can i add defined values to the ComboBox (which is a custom control in my case - refers to `System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox`)

This doesn't need to be dynamic or editable at all. Just a ComboBox with Fixed Values. Any Ideas?

Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: Forgot to mention: I am using VS 2013 Ultimate and it's a Lightswitch Desktop Application in C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a specific reason this needs to be a custom control? You could just add a Local Property of type String by clicking Add Data Item and then setting up a Choice List.

Add the Local Property String to your screen and then click Choice List in the Properties. Value and Display name don't need to be the same thing but I feel like it helps.

[image: Choice List]

The result is a drop down list of your choices. In your code, test for whatever you put for Value.

[image: Choice List Display]

Comment: No there is no reason! This works perfect, thank you! :)

Comment: I told you there wasn't to the best of my knowledge. This is a better solution. Every day is a school day. :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think to do this would be to add a table for your values as you cannot add a unbound checkbox to the screen to the best of my knowledge:

[image]

Then on your screen, click "Add Data Item", select the "Local Property" option then from the "Type" list choose your table name (PaperSize).

[image]

That will create a property in the list of properties down the left hand side - probably near the bottom. You just need to drag that to where you would like to see it on screen. That will produce a combo box of paper sizes for you that you could then read using:

`string PaperSize = this.PaperSize.PaperSizeName;`

The only thing you may want to consider is adding an editable grid screen for your paper sizes so you have someway to add/modify/remove them.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was hoping that there is a more "slight" way of doing this but at least this works as it should ;-)